# Characterization of variational symmetries

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, noethers-theorem, variational-calculus, invariants

I have the following definition of variational symmetry, this is from Bruce Van Brunt's Calculus of Variations book

Suppose we have a functional of the form
$$
J(y)= \int_{x_{0}}^{x_{1}} f(x,y,y')dx
$$
and a smooth transformation $X=\theta (x,y: \epsilon)$ , $Y=\psi (x,y: \epsilon)$ where $\epsilon$ is a parameter.

**Definition.** The functional $J$ is invariant under the above transformation if, for all $\epsilon$ sufficiently small, in any subinterval $[a,b] \subset [x_{0},x_{1}]$ we have that
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x,y,y')dx= \displaystyle \int_{a_{\epsilon}}^{b_{\epsilon}} f(X,Y,Y')dX
$$
for all smooth functions $y$ defined on $[a,b]$. Here, $a_{\epsilon}=\theta (a,y(a): \epsilon)$, $b_{\epsilon}=\theta (b,y(b): \epsilon)$

And, $ \epsilon$ is a parameter such that $\theta (x,y;  0)=x$ and $\psi (x,y;  0)=y$.

Once said that, I would appreciate your help for a rigorous proof of the converse of the following theorem

> **Theorem 9.4.1.** Let
> $$
> J(y)= \int_{x_{0}}^{x_{1}} f(x,y,y')dx.
> $$
> The transformation above with infinitesimal generators $\xi$ and $\eta$ is a variational symmetry for $J$ if and only if
> $$
> \xi \displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \eta \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + ( \eta ' - y' \xi ' ) \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} + \xi ' f=0 \tag{9.38}
> $$
> for any smooth function $y$ on $ [x_{0},x_{1}] $.
> Here,
> $$
>  \xi (x,y)=  \frac{\partial \theta}{ \partial \epsilon }   \Big |_{(x,y;0)}^{},
> $$
> $$
>  \eta (x,y)=  \frac{\partial \psi}{ \partial \epsilon }   \Big |_{(x,y;0)}^{}.
> $$

I have been thinking about it , but, I believe that, at least under this definition of invariance the converse is false. The author refers us to the book *Introduction to the calculus of variations and its applications* by Frederic Wan for a proof, however, I see nowhere that the converse is proved.

Any help?

**Remark:**

The reason for which I think the converse it's false is because if we consider the functional
$$
\displaystyle \int_{x_{0}}^{x_{1}} xy'^2 dx
$$
And the transformation

$$
X=x+2 \epsilon x ln(x), Y=(1+ \epsilon ) y
$$

Then, equation $\xi  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \eta \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + ( \eta ' - y' \xi ' ) \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} + \xi ' f=0$ holds , but, I think there is no way that the above transformation is a variational symmetry since

$$
XY ' ^2 dX= \left( xy'^2+ \frac{(x \epsilon ^2+ 2 \epsilon ^3 x ln(x))y'^2}{(1+2 \epsilon ln(x)+ 2 \epsilon)}   \right) dx
$$

And this , definitely does not agree with the definition. Or am I wrong? If so, why? :(

**Update:** Here are the computations that shows equation $\xi  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \eta \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + ( \eta ' - y' \xi ' ) \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} + \xi ' f=0$ holds:

We have that $\xi=2xln(x)$ and $\eta=y$, so
$$\xi f_{x}+ \eta f_{y}+(\eta' - y' \xi ') f_{y'}+ \xi' f = 2x ln(x) y'^2 + (y'-y'(2ln(x)+2))2xy'+(2ln(x)+2)xy'^2=2xln(x)y'^2-2xy'^2-4y'^2xln(x)+2xy'^2ln(x)+2xy'^2=0$$

Comment: Which pages in Brunt? Ah, found it: Theorem 9.4.1, p. 213.

Comment: @Qmechanic yes exactly, and page 189 in Wan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It seems that OP is pondering the following question:

   > Does the off-shell Noether identity$^1$ (9.38) imply that the functional $J(\epsilon)$ has a 1-parameter off-shell symmetry for sufficiently small *finite* $\epsilon>0$?

   This is of course *not* necessarily the case. We can always change the transformations for $X$ and $Y$ at order ${\cal O}(\epsilon^2)$ in a manner that breaks the *finite* symmetry of $J(\epsilon)$ without altering eq. (9.38).
2. In contrast the correct statement is:

   > The off-shell Noether identity (9.38) holds iff there is an *infinitesimal* off-shell symmetry
   > $$\left.\frac{dJ(\epsilon)}{d\epsilon}\right|_{\epsilon=0}~=~0.$$

References:

1. B. van Brunt,  [*The Calculus of Variations*](https://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-b97436/), 2004; p. 213.
2. F. Wan, [*Intro to the Calculus of Variations and its Applications*](https://books.google.cz/books/about/Introduction_To_The_Calculus_of_Variatio.html?id=ZClJz0emcb4C), 1995; p. 189.

--

$^1$ The following is not part of OP's question, but if the reader  wonders what the off-shell Noether identity (9.38) has to do with [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem), let us mention that it can be rewritten as
$$\begin{align} 0~=~& \eta \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + ( \dot{\eta} -  \dot{\xi} \dot{y}) \frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{y}} + \dot{\xi}f +\xi  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cr
~=~&\eta_0 \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} +  \dot{\eta}_0  \frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{y}} + \frac{d(\xi f)}{dx} \cr
~=~&\eta_0 \underbrace{\frac{\delta J}{\delta y}}_{\text{EL eq.}} + \dot{Q} ,\end{align}\tag{9.38} $$
where $$Q~=~\eta_0\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{y}}+\xi f$$
is the (bare) Noether charge; where
$$\eta_0~=~\eta-\xi\dot{y}$$
is the vertical generator; and where dot means a total derivative $\frac{d}{dx}$. In particular, we deduce that the Noether charge $Q$ is conserved on-shell.

Comment: Thanks! :) That makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

The converse is essentially what you can get from Picard's theorem for ODE.

The counter example is not working. In your case $\xi=2x\ln x$ and $\eta=y$.

So you have $2x\ln x\cdot y'^2+ y\cdot 0 + (0-y'(2\ln x + 2))\cdot 2xy'+ 0$, which doesn't seem to be 0.

Update: I was wrong in interpreting the conditions, the OP is right, the condition will take $\eta$'s dependence on x through y in the evaluation of $\eta'$, which should have been defined as $\eta'(x,y)=\frac{\partial\eta}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial\eta}{\partial y} y'$.

So the counterexample stands, and the condition would only work if $\eta_\epsilon(x,y)$ and $\xi_\epsilon(x,y)$ are defined for a small neighborhood of $\epsilon=0$ with the above condition. That's also why the above ends up being almost true up to a $O(\epsilon^2)$ term, since the condition is satisfied up to a deviation for $\eta_\epsilon$ and $\xi_\epsilon$ away from $\epsilon=0$.

Update again: My guess is that the condition was actually to use $(\xi,\eta)$ as a 2D vector field, as the generator of diffeomorphism on the 2D plane, and  compute $(\theta,\psi)=\exp((\xi,\eta)\epsilon).$

I figured the exponential map for OP's example can be worked out in closed form. So here it is:
$X=x^{e^{2\epsilon}},\quad Y=y e^\epsilon.$

Now $\frac{\partial X}{\partial x} = e^{2\epsilon}\frac{X}{x},$ and $Y'=\frac{\partial Y}{\partial y} \frac{d y}{d x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial X}=e^{\epsilon} y' \frac{x}{X} e^{-2\epsilon},$ which lead to $XY^{'2}dX=xy^{'2}dx$ precisely.

Comment: As you said, $\xi (x,y) =2xln(x)$, $\eta (x,y)=y$ , but we have also that $f_{x}=y'^2$, $f_{y'}+=0$ and $f_{y'}=2xy'$, so $\xi f_{x}+ \eta f_{y}+(\eta' - y' \xi ') f_{y'}+ \xi' f = 2x ln(x) y'^2 + (y'-y'(2ln(x)+2))2xy'+(2ln(x)+2)xy'^2=2xln(x)y'^2-2xy'^2-4y'^2xln(x)+2xy'^2ln(x)+2xy'^2=0$

Comment: That's all in the above expression, I put a cdot to separate those coming from the different parts.

Comment: And neither the term containing $\ln x$ nor the term not containing it would cancel out.

Comment: you have forgettten one term, see my comment

Comment: Ah. I see the misunderstanding. $\eta'=0$. It's just like $f_y=0$.

Comment: Don't include the dependence of $\eta$ to $x$ through $y$. The transformation from (x,y) to (X,Y) is to be treated as a change of coordinate systems.

Comment: My feeling is that the converse is false. The direct statement should arise by simply computing the $\epsilon$ derivative at $\epsilon=0$ of the identity stating the invariance property and exploiting arbitrariness of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: The converse is true, I guess, if assuming a further requirement on the variations: they have to produce a one-parameter group of transformations...

Comment: @ValterMoretti that's precisely how arise the direct statement, and I totally agree that is true, but not the converse.

Comment: ferolimen and @ValterMoretti You were right: they have to produce a one-parameter group, which I think is possible by the exponential map of 2D vector fields. So I edited my answer. It's just that $\theta, \psi$ cannot be arbitrary mappings that produces $\xi,\eta$, but their exponential functions. BTW, there was a typo in the condition in OP: the last term is $\xi' f$ instead of $\eta' f$.

Comment: @YTong yes it's true, there is a typo, I will correct it now , thanks!

Comment: @ferolimen I calculated the exponential map of your example. Check it out:)

Comment: @YTong I have already checked it, thanks! :)